# Swift -AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction Misalignment when Merging Videos

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, avmutablevideocomposition

I followed the [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10857372-how-to-play-record-and-merge-videos-in-ios-and-swift) to merge videos. The finished result is 1 merged video where portrait videos are at the top of the screen and landscape videos are at the bottom of the screen. In the image below the portrait videos plays first and then landscape video plays after it. The landscape video is from the Photos Library.

[image]

code:

```
var arrOfAssets = [AVAsset]()

func mergVideos() {

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
            
    let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let audioCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    
    var count = 0
    var insertTime = CMTime.zero
    var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    
    for videoAsset in arrOfAssets {

        let audioTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0]

        do {
    
            try videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: insertTime)
            try audioCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: audioTrack, at: insertTime)
    
            let layerInstruction = videoCompositionLayerInstruction(videoCompositionTrack!, asset: videoAsset, count: count)
    
            let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: insertTime, duration: videoAsset.duration)
            videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

            instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)
    
            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAsset.duration)

            count += 1

        } catch { }
    }
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.instructions = instructions
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    // ...
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
}
```

Ray Wenderlich Code:

```
func videoCompositionLayerInstruction(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset, count: Int) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
    
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
    
    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    
    let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)
    
    var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
    if assetInfo.isPortrait {
        
        scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor), at: .zero)
        
    } else {
        
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
            .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
        if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
            let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
            let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
            let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
            concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
        }
        instruction.setTransform(concat, at: .zero)
    }
    
    if count == 0 {
        instruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: asset.duration)
    }
    
    return instruction
}

func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
    var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
      var isPortrait = false
      let tfA = transform.a
      let tfB = transform.b
      let tfC = transform.c
      let tfD = transform.d

      if tfA == 0 && tfB == 1.0 && tfC == -1.0 && tfD == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
      } else if tfA == 0 && tfB == -1.0 && tfC == 1.0 && tfD == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
      } else if tfA == 1.0 && tfB == 0 && tfC == 0 && tfD == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
      } else if tfA == -1.0 && tfB == 0 && tfC == 0 && tfD == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
      }
      return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
}
```

I also followed the code from this Medium [post](https://medium.com/goodrequest/merge-multiple-videos-with-correct-orientations-on-ios-in-swift-e24548037279). It sets the render size to a default of `let renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280.0, height: 720.0)` as opposed the Ray's which uses the entire screen.

The 1280/720 results are the portrait videos are centered correctly but with the landscape videos the sound plays however the videos are no where on screen. I didn't add a picture of landscape because it's just a black screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I got it working for both portrait and landscape.

[image]

I tested this answer with videos recorded in portrait, landscape left/right, upside down, front camera, and the back camera. I haven't had any issues. I'm far from a `CGAffineTransform` expert, so if anyone has a better answer please post it.

Ray Wenderlich's merging code works, but it doesn't work for videos with different orientations. I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161545/4833705) to check the properties of the `preferredTransform` for the `orientation` check.

I also used a [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625731/4833705) answer for the `portrait orientation` part and a [downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334486/4833705) answer for the `landscape orientation` part. The downvoted answer led me to a his [GitHub](https://github.com/vabe1337/VBVideoEditor/blob/main/VideoEditor.swift) where the landscape code was **incorrect** but close enough for me to make adjustments to it to get it working correctly.

One thing to point out is the comments from [@DonMag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782669/4833705) told me about the benefit of using **720x1280**. The code below will merge all of the videos together with a `renderSize` of **720x1280** which will keep them the same size.

code:

```
var arrOfAssets = [AVAsset]()

// class property
let renderSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280) // for higher quality use CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920)

func mergVideos() {

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
            
    let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let audioCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    
    var count = 0
    var insertTime = CMTime.zero
    var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    
    for videoAsset in arrOfAssets {

        guard let firstTrack = videoAsset.tracks.first, let _ = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else { continue }

        do {
    
            try videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: insertTime)

            if let audioTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first {
                try audioCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: audioTrack, at: insertTime)
            }

            let layerInstruction = videoCompositionLayerInstruction(firstTrack, asset: videoAsset, count: count)
    
            let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: insertTime, duration: videoAsset.duration)
            videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

            instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)
    
            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAsset.duration)

            count += 1

        } catch {
            // you should always print out the error
        }
    }
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.instructions = instructions
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = self.renderSize // <--- **** IMPORTANT ****

    // ...
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
}
```

Most **important part** of this answer that replaces the RW code:

```
func videoCompositionLayerInstruction(_ firstTrack: AVAssetTrack, asset: AVAsset, count: Int) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: firstTrack)

    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]            
    let t = assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform // new transform fix 
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(t)

    if assetInfo.isPortrait {

        let scaleToFitRatio = self.renderSize.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        var finalTransform = assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)

        // This was needed in the case of the OP's answer that I used for the portrait part. I haven't tested this but this is what he said: "(if video not taking entire screen and leaving some parts black - don't know when actually needed so you'll have to try and see when it's needed)"
        if assetInfo.orientation == .rightMirrored || assetInfo.orientation == .leftMirrored {
            finalTransform = finalTransform.translatedBy(x: -transform.ty, y: 0)
        }
        instruction.setTransform(finalTransform, at: CMTime.zero)

    } else {

        let renderRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.renderSize.width, height: self.renderSize.height)
        let videoRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: assetTrack.naturalSize).applying(assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform)

        let scale = renderRect.width / videoRect.width
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: renderRect.width / videoRect.width, y: (videoRect.height * scale) / assetTrack.naturalSize.height)
        let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: .zero, y: ((self.renderSize.height - (videoRect.height * scale))) / 2)

        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.fixedPreferredTransform.concatenating(transform).concatenating(translate), at: .zero)
    }

    if count == 0 {
        instruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: asset.duration)
    }
    
    return instruction
}
```

New orientation check:

```
func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
    var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
    var isPortrait = false
    
    if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .rightMirrored
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .leftMirrored
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
    } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
    }
}
```

preferredTransform [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161545/4833705):

```
extension AVAssetTrack {
    
    var fixedPreferredTransform: CGAffineTransform {
        var t = preferredTransform
        switch(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d) {
        case (1, 0, 0, 1):
            t.tx = 0
            t.ty = 0
        case (1, 0, 0, -1):
            t.tx = 0
            t.ty = naturalSize.height
        case (-1, 0, 0, 1):
            t.tx = naturalSize.width
            t.ty = 0
        case (-1, 0, 0, -1):
            t.tx = naturalSize.width
            t.ty = naturalSize.height
        case (0, -1, 1, 0):
            t.tx = 0
            t.ty = naturalSize.width
        case (0, 1, -1, 0):
            t.tx = naturalSize.height
            t.ty = 0
        case (0, 1, 1, 0):
            t.tx = 0
            t.ty = 0
        case (0, -1, -1, 0):
            t.tx = naturalSize.height
            t.ty = naturalSize.width
        default:
            break
        }
        return t
    }
}
```